# printk usage simple error

Tags: c, linux-kernel

receiving error in small snippet when trying to print message in dmesg

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>


printk(KERN_INFO "\n hello there I am in dmesg \n");
```

**Error: avotstbr99:root:/tmp # gcc dmessage.c

dmessage.c:4: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant**

Comment: Is this the sum total of your code?  Do you have a main?

Comment: that's all the code?

Comment: yes that's all, I thought printk would display kernel buffer message , moreover won't it suppose to be compiled fine simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it should be something like this :

```
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>   
#include <linux/init.h>     

static int __init YourDemsgCode_init(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "\n hello there I am in dmesg \n");
return 0;
}

static void __exit YourDemsgCode_exit(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye dmesg\n");
}

module_init(YourDemsgCode_init);
module_exit(YourDemsgCode_exit);
```

Then you need to compile it using Makefile , a normal gcc won't work.

```
obj-m += YourDemsgCode.o


all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: thanks Hemant , so we cannot have our kernel buffer message printed with only printk, it is something to be loaded with the module ?

Comment: @theartist33 Right , but great job trying to learn it , keep it up.